# Xcode swift UIView bottom bar does not display

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview

I'm a beginner in iOs development but I'm a web wedeveloper.

I was trying some small things on Xcode and I face a problem without finding solution or usefull information on the web, take a look to my UiView below
[image]

which is quite large, and has a bottom bar with Done button, and and another bar with some button.

But when I'm running the simulator, I can't see this bottom bar guide, I do have a button on it, I have an action on it, the "Hidden" field is not selected.

Any idea why it's happenning (Using Xcode 6 beta 7)?

[image]

Comment: have you added constraints to your project in the storyboard?

Comment: No didn't added any constraints

Comment: Does it work now?I am just as a beginner as you but from what I saw in every tutorial is that constraints play a really big role.so never forget them

Comment: While removing the autolayout, I don't have anymore the problem of wide screens, it was likely something like ipad adaptation, but I am still not seeing the bottom bar, check here a breand new application, only for iphone https://www.evernote.com/shard/s161/sh/3f19e8f7-6700-4f2d-8e8f-649aa081113e/7928becba98062e2dd56035aa7669270

Answer (score 0):

Set left and right border constraints to 0, and "center horizontally" constraint as well.